# select default value in first dropdown when i click on second one

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have two dropdowns , i want onclick or onchange from one , the second set to default value and vice-versa

```
//first dropdown   
 @Html.DropDownList("Agent_Id", null, "Séléctionnez un élément", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control select2 unselected", required = "Séléctionnez un élément" }) 

   // second drop down
 @Html.DropDownList("TypeEntite_Id", null, "Séléctionnez un élément", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control select2 unselected", required = "Séléctionnez un élément" })
```

I tried using jquery code to handle the issue but i couldn't figure out the proper way

```
        $('.unselected').change(function () {


            $(this).addClass('selected');

            if ($('.unselected').hasClass('selected')) {
                $('.unselected').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
            }

            if ($(this).hasClass('selected') )
            {
                $('.unselected').not(this).each(function () {
                    $('.unselected').val("");
                });

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// hook to select change
$('.form-control.select2').change(function() {

    // remove unselected and add selected css class
    $(this).toggleClass('selected unselected');

    // unselect all other .unselected values
    $('.form-control.select').not($(this)).removeClass('selected').addClass('unselected').val('');

});
```

Comment: Should never use `click` on a `<select>`. Will trigger twice: once when opening, once when selection made

Comment: @charlietfl nope. If you click but not change its value then `change` won’t be fired.

Comment: So... no reason to do anything then. just suggesting that using `click` on `<select>` is not a good practice

Comment: @charlietfl well question specifies that the event must fire on click and on change

Comment: That doesn't mean question is right and OP understands the implications

Comment: @charlietfl then why answer the question if you think so?

Comment: because using change is all that is needed...think about it a bit more

Comment: well your answer , logiclly should work , but it didin't

Comment: @OuSsamaChallal how’s that? Is there some sort of delay in the selects options loading? Can you provide the rendered html?

Answer (score 0):

Can simplify this down to

```js
var $selects = $('select.select2').change(function() {  
  $selects.not(this).val('');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select2">
  <option value="">-- Choose something --</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select class="select2">
  <option value="">-- Choose something --</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: when i apply your jquery code , there's no change in my app

Comment: your code is 100% right , it worked when i reload thepage , i don't understand